# How to find ids that requires action based on 3 tables?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-views

I'm working on my first django project which is a sport betting app.
My models are:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    home_team = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    away_team = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class GameResult(models.Model):
    gameid = models.ForeignKey(Game)
    result = models.IntegerField(default=None)

class GameBet(models.Model):
    gameid = models.ForeignKey(Game)
    bet = models.IntegerField(default=None)
    userid = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I'm trying to create a view that shows only pending games, which means they have no result (easy part) and no bet placed yet.

Here the problem is - in my database I have only bets that was made, like:

```
gameid| userid | userbet
23    | 10     | 2
23    | 11     | 1
23    | 12     | 0
```

and I'm looking for somethig like this:

```
gameid| userid | userbet
24    | 10     | 1
24    | 11     | 0
```

When userid #12 hasn't made his bet yet - so it is missing in the database and game should be in his pending games list.

My current logic is that I know ids of all games, I know ids of games with result and I know ids of games that I placed my bet.

How do I connect these dots and find out  games that I still have to bet?

```
all_games               = Game.objects.get()
games_with_result       = GameResult.objects.filter(result__isnull=False)
games_with_players_bet  = GameBet.objects.filter(userid_id=selected_player)
```

Or maybe I should rebuild my database? I appreciate all the answers

Comment: OT: in which game a result is represented with one integer?

Comment: first team vs second team :
1 = first team win
0 = draw
2 = second team win

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use [exclude](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) on a queryset:

```
all_games = Game.objects.all()
results = GameResult.objects.filter(result__isnull=False)
games_without_result = all_games.exclude(pk__in=[r.gameid.pk for r in results])
bets_from_player = GameBet.objects.filter(userid_id=selected_player)
owing_games = games_without_result.exclude(pk__in=[bet.gameid.pk for bet in bets_from_player])
```

The `GameResult` model might move as a field (`result = models.IntegerField(default=None)`) into `Game`. This should work as long as you only expect one result per game. As a benefit you can easily query for games without results.

```
games_without_result = Game.objects.filter(result__isnull=True)
```

Comment: Sorry for that many edits after the first post - now the answer should fit your question ;)

Comment: thank you very much @dahrens it works like a charm!

I've just started playing with exclude, but using lists of ids but your solution is definitely better, great answer. much appreciated :)

Comment: you are welcome. The above solution uses lists, too. But it hides them behind the syntactic sugar of [list comprehention](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).  Note that querysets are not executed directly, but under several circumstances. Iterating over them is one of them.